# adding multiple users to active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm writing c# code which will interact with the active directory, and my question is is there a fast way to add multiple users to a directory entry. I am kind of new to active directory. What I have found out so far, is that I can use DirectoryEntrie class's Add method to add a user. So, using a loop statement I would be able to add multiple users.However, I was wondering... would this not take long, if I had 500 loops? Isn't there a better, faster method,(let's say Addrange(Ienumerable)) which only performs a single time, but having a list or array as an parameter?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you post the current code you have? Just the bit where you are adding users is fine.

Comment: You could potentially use the [LDIFDE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555636) tool - but that's not a C# code solution, obviously.

Comment: Well, after doing a bit ore research on this matter, I may have found the answer myself, at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180904(v=vs.80).aspx ; I'll try it out and let you guys know if it works or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a batch of users at once, from the perspective of Directory Services. You'll have to use the loop.

Comment: It seems you are right, what I thought about addrange method is wrong, addrange is only used to add already existing members to a group.